# Dynamic merge in SQL LANGUAGE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have dynamic merge in snowflake in JAVASCRIPT store procedure, something like this:

```
snowflake.execute({sqlText: `
                MERGE INTO ${TARGET_TABLE} T 
                USING (SELECT * FROM ${SOURCE_OBJECT}) S 
                ON ${rm.map(r => `COALESCE(T."${r}", ''-1'') = COALESCE(S."${r}", ''-1'')`).join('' AND '')}

                
                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
                    ${col.map(c => `T."${c}" = S."${c}"`).join('', '')}

                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
                    ${col.map(c => `"${c}"`).join('', '')}
                ) VALUES (
                    ${col.map(c => `S."${c}"`).join('', '')}    
                );`});
```

is there a way to do the same in SQL LANGUAGE?

Comment: snowflake.execute({sqlText: MERGE INTO ${TARGET_TABLE} T  USING (SELECT * FROM ${SOURCE_OBJECT}) S  ON ${rm.map(r =>COALESCE(T."${r}", ''-1'') = COALESCE(S."${r}", ''-1'')`).join('' AND '')}

            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
                ${col.map(c => `T."${c}" = S."${c}"`).join('', '')}

            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
                ${col.map(c => `"${c}"`).join('', '')}
            ) VALUES (
                ${col.map(c => `S."${c}"`).join('', '')}    
            );`});

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing using Snowflake Scripting (SQL):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html

Comment: This is not what i had in mind. what i need is to put the list of target column and list of source column as a parameter to pass in the dynamic merge. Also I dont know how to pass the  stetment after "on" through variable. in sql its easy but in snowflake it is not.

Comment: I don't think it's too much different from JavaScript. You said it's easy in SQL, do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? Can you share a working script?